# Merge two Dataframes on two columns with different length by closest match

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, difflib

I want to merge these example dataframes:

1. How to get the closest matches in a new df?

```py
df1:

name           age      department
DJ Griffin     27       FD
Harris Smith   33       RD


df2:

name               age      department
D.J. Griffin III   27       FD
Harris Smith       33       RD
Miles Jones        58       RD
```

The result should look like:

```py
df3:

name         age      department   name_y
DJ Griffin     27       FD         D.J. Griffin III
Harris Smith   33       RD         Harris Smith
```

Used Difflib but got an error, cause of the different length of the dfs.

```py
import pandas as pd
import difflib

df1 = pd.DataFrame([["DJ Griffin", 27, "FD"], ["Harris Smith", 33, "RD"]], columns=["name", "age", "department"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["D.J. Griffin III", 27, "FD"], ["Harris Smith", 33, "RD"], ["Miles Jones", 58, "RD"]], columns=["name", "age", "department"])

df2['name_y'] = df2['name']

df2['name'] = df2['name'].apply(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, df1['name'])[0])
```

Result:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

2. How to find the closest match by two columns when there is another Harris Smith with the age of 45?

```py
For the duplicate Harris Smith case

df1:

name           age      department
DJ Griffin     27       FD
Harris Smith   33       RD
Harris Smith   45       BA

df2:

name               age      department
D.J. Griffin III   27       FD
Harris Smith       33       RD
Harris Smith       45       BA
Miles Jones        58       RD
```

The result should look like:

```py
df3:

name         age      department   name_y
DJ Griffin     27       FD         D.J. Griffin III
Harris Smith   33       RD         Harris Smith
Harris Smith   45       BA         Harris Smith
```

```py
import pandas as pd
import difflib

df1 = pd.DataFrame([["DJ Griffin", 27, "FD"], ["Harris Smith", 33, "RD"], ["Harris Smith", 45, "BA"]], columns=["name", "age", "department"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["D.J. Griffin III", 27, "FD"], ["Harris Smith", 33, "RD"], ["Harris Smith", 45, "BA"], ["Miles Jones", 58, "RD"]], columns=["name", "age", "department"])

df2['name_y'] = df2['name']
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what is the expected output for 2- (and please update the input)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added input/output for the 2nd question.

Comment: Then you should probably keep all matches, explode them and merge on match+age

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue arises when you have zero match, slicing `[0]` is not possible.

You could use instead:

```
df2['name'].apply(lambda x: next(iter(difflib.get_close_matches(x, df1['name'])), pd.NA))
```

or

```
df2['name'].apply(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, df1['name'])).str[0]
```

output:

```
0      DJ Griffin
1    Harris Smith
2             NaN
Name: name, dtype: object
```

##### update:

```
df1.merge(df2[['name', 'age']]
 .assign(name_y=df2['name'],
         name=df2['name'].apply(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, df1['name'])))
 .explode('name')
 .drop_duplicates(),
 on=['name', 'age']
)
```

output:

```
           name  age department            name_y
0    DJ Griffin   27         FD  D.J. Griffin III
1  Harris Smith   33         RD      Harris Smith
2  Harris Smith   45         BA      Harris Smith
```